# Do I need submit buttons with ajax applications

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Posting data to the server needs a form-tag.

But do I also need a button of type 'submit' when I use ajax/jquery?

Can I not just interrupt the button click and do my own ajax request?

Comment: No, you don't *need* a submit button, or even a button at all, if you don't want them. Now whether or not it's a good idea to not have a submit button absolutely depends on the application.

Comment: No. You can trigger an ajax request any way you want.. on click, on blur on change.. whatsoever..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and technically you don't even need a form tag if you want to serialize the POST data yourself.

Comment: "if you want to serialize the POST data yourself." You mean when I use javascript objects and use JSON.stringify(data) on it?

Comment: You could do that, sure. All I meant was that ajax gives you the ability to communicate with your backend in whatever manner you want. POST with postdata (that you can build, or if you're using jQuery, you could just use the `.serialize()`) or POST with querystring parameters. You could even use GET should you choose to, it's up to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ajax then you don't *technically*, *need* a form tag or a submit button.

Having them gives you convenient, semantic elements with logical events to bind the JavaScript to.

Having them is needed for the JS to be [unobtrusive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (which is a best practise).

Comment: So I should use forms (best practise) but I can use a button of type button (stupid...) and just do the e.preventDefault() and then my own ajax stuff right? So the only situation where I need not to use forms is having a single page app which really can only work with javascript...

Comment: You should use a form, and a regular submit button and make the form work with a normal form submission to the action, then add JavaScript to do it via Ajax which binds to the submit event of the form and calls `e.preventDefault()`.